# Disable availability status for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, status

Is it possible to disable the availability status (Busy, Available...) for external users?

So, users within the company may see the available status of other users but external companies may not see the availability status from our users.

I haven't found any option which facilitates this. The only settings regarding external access are these:
[image: Teams external access]

Is this something that could be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to hide availability status for external users.

Please vote for this feature in Microsoft Teams UserVoice:

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40895812-hide-user-presence-from-external-contacts

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted this request hopefully it will be implemented soon as it would improve privacy for our users

Answer (score 0):

**Currently it is possible to define the present status for external contacts but only tenant wide and without exceptions.**

Explanation in the following post:

Hide presence status for external contacts
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/8018f5b3-ce93-ec11-a81b-000d3ae2cae1

Unfortunately "microsoftteams.uservoice.com" is offline